# how to position tooltip just after one div ends? when div ends in second line, then also tooltip appears in first line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement to put a tooltip after the content. I am facing problem to make it responsive, as when content is rendering in two line, the tooltip component is still rendering at first line.
Here is the code i tried.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-lg-8"> This content is going beyound one line, Then the problem arrives because the tooltip is still at first line. But it should be in second line where this content ends</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" title="this information is about div one's content">tooltip</div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please suggest how to achieve it.. [Here is the plunker url for the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/SrRX7Oz0FKSNNM5dKLvG?p=preview)

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a plunker?

Comment: @Shruti i see nothing wrong with this code

Comment: @RachelGallen I need to show tooltip just when div's content end. problem is when div content end in second line, then also my tooltip appears in first line.

Answer (score -1):

This is from bootstrap by default to be the right corner at the page.So you must rewrite the default bootstrap(which it will work until the new update)Or see how they are made it and copy from them to make your own custom tooltip.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: i don`t have reputation for a comment i make research and i thought that i  leave usefull information about his/her problem.